# Installing Java 6 on Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, java-6

Is it possible to install the latest JDK on Mac OS 10.5? What are the best options, considering that the Apple-supplied version is 1.5?

**Update:** I am trying to install JDeveloper 11, which requires JDK 6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have an Intel Mac with a Core 2 Duo, go to Applications/Java and run Java Preferences.app

You'll be able to select "Java SE 6" as your default java version (version 5 is still the shipping default on the OS for compatibility, I guess).

Comment: It's actually Applications > Utilities > Java, thanks though!

Answer (score 7):

Depending on your hardware the [latest version](http://developer.apple.com/java/) Apple supplies actually is Java 6, but it is not activated as the default version to use. Apple supplies Java 6 only for 64-bit Intel Macs (i.e. not for original Core Duo Macs). For older Macs, you could try the [OpenJDK port of Java 6 for Mac](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/static/soylatte/) (SoyLatte).

Answer (score 1):

Apple provides Java 6 (1.6) for Leopard (OS X 10.5) as an update, however only the 64-bit version. So, if your Mac is not a 64-bit Intel, then you won't have Java 6 on Leopard.

If you do have a 64-bit Intel, then ensure that you install the latest OS updates, especially the Java ones to make sure you get Java 1.6. Also, you still need to set Java 6 as the default VM in your Java Preferences, as it defaults to Java 1.5.

Currently, the easiest solution if you have a 32-bit Intel processor is to upgrade to Snow Leopard, which includes 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Java 6.

Answer (score 0):

[OS X does have Java 6](http://developer.apple.com/java/) after Update 1.  The version number you are referring to is the version **of** Java 6.  Do you receive any errors while installing JDeveloper 11?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a software update.  Here's a [blog post](http://gephi.org/support/install-java-6-mac-os-x-leopard/) that describes it.

Answer (score 0):

JDeveloper like netbeans and eclipse provide a configuration file(usually a .conf) where you can update a jdkhome attribute addresing the path of your jdk6 installation, as mentioned before you can get it from [OpenJDK port of Java 6 for Mac](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/static/soylatte/).

Answer (score 0):

You also need to be aware that:

- if you have an alias "CurrentJDK" and if that alias is "broken" then you must delete it to install a new JDK.
- Deleting that "alias" will solver troubles.

Answer (score -1):

It is. Check here: [Apple support](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1856)