# Java 6 on Mac PowerPC with Mac OS X 10.4

Tags: java, macos

Is it possible to get Java 6 running on a Mac PowerPC with Mac OS X 10.4?  AFAIK [SoyLatte](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/static/soylatte/) is only available for Intel processors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in addition to not working on PPC, Apple's Java6 [does not work on 32 bit Intel](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1856) either. And there are other restrictions for the new Java6, leading to opinions such as [this](http://java.dzone.com/news/java-6-mac-worsest-release-eve).

Answer (score 6):

As of December 2009, a beta of OpenJDK 7 for OS X 10.5 PPC is available at http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/static/soylatte/ -- haven't tried it, and it's not quite what you were after, but it's the first I've seen so far of Java >=6 on any PPC OS X version! More details at http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/2009/12/index.html .

Comment: The most recent soylatte seems to be available there: https://wikis.oracle.com/display/OpenJDK/BSDPort - soylatte has been integrated in the BSDPort project.

Answer (score 4):

Someone yesterday recommended SoyLatte for PPC ([Installing Java 6 on Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607945/installing-java-6-on-mac-os/607966#607966)), and in fact these instructions seem to support his theory (read the comments where someone claims it works on his PPC): http://blog.adsdevshop.com/2008/02/26/installing-the-jdk-16-on-mac-os-x/

YMMV :-) Or try building from source. Again, YMMV :-)

Comment: I read the comment there, and tried it myself but hasn't worked.  :(

Comment: Shoot. Sorry you had to be the guinea pig.

Answer (score 3):

yes there is a 1.6 Version for PPC coming from the 10.4 Developer preview.

http://images.spelpunt.nl/javase6release1dp6.dmg

You can't install it via installer but go to /Volumes/Java\ SE\ 6\ Release\ 1/JavaSE6Release1.pkg/ and copy Archive.pax.gz to your Desktop; gzip -d Archive.pax.gz
and then pax or double click on Archive.pax.

Now there is the package content. Under /Your Desktop/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/bin you can find a PPC 1.6 JDK ;-) beta but an working 1.6 JDK.

Copy 1.6.0 to /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Version ..
run /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/bin/java

Thats it ...

Comment: The link is DEAD now. It gives a 404 NOT FOUND etc. etc. etc.

Answer (score 2):

There is one out there that works and runs on ppc tiger:

1. get the .dmg and install it
2. su root; cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions; ls
3. make sure you see '1.6 -> 1.6.0' CurrentJDK -> 1.5
4. rm CurrentJDK (removes symbolic link, not the jdk)
5. ln -s 1.6 CurrentJDK
6. java -version

java version "1.6.0-dp"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0-dp-b88-34)
Java HotSpot(TM) Core VM (build 1.6.0-b88-17-release, interpreted mode, sharing)

Don't know where the package was downloaded from.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not very useful if you don't know where the package comes from…

Answer (score 1):

The only Java 6 for PowerPC I have seen is for Linux:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/linux/download.html

I am afraid you will have to stay with Java 5 on Mac OS X on PowerPC.

Answer (score 1):

If some is still searching for the answer, I have the solution, I took it from Mac Insights:

Java 1.6 on Tiger, on PowerPC or Intel

Installer: https://hell.meiert.org/core/dmg/java-6-dp.dmg

If you run the installer on a fully updated Tiger system, it’ll inform you that “This volume contains a newer version of Java.” So, first move aside the files it’s checking.

**sudo mv /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Resources/Info-macos.plist{,.old}
sudo mv /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Resources/version.plist{,.old}**

After running the installer, open the new “Java Preferences” in /Applications/Utilities/Java/Java SE 6. Set “Use version” to “Java SE 6” and reorder the list in “Java Application Runtime Settings” so “Java SE 6” is first. After you click “Save” and quit, confirm that Java 6 is active by running java -version.

Done.

Source: https://ericfromcanada.github.io/output/2018/java-6-tiger-leopard.html

Answer (score -1):

For my surprise I had Java 1.5 in 10.4.6, just followed the steps given in the link to make it the default JRE: [Java 1.5 in 10.4.6](http://techmindviews.blogspot.com/2011/10/changing-java-version-mac-1046.html)

Comment: -1: This is not helpful for the given question, which was about installing Java 6 (aka 1.6).

Answer (score -1):

here is the down loadable dmg for the java 10.6

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33087/apple-java-for-mac-os-x-10.6

Comment: that's a link to a Java update for Snow Leopard, and therefore only runs on modern Intel Macs. It's not helpful for running on PowerPc