# c++ coding for power-pc

Tags: java, c++, powerpc

anyone know any cpp compilers for power-pc? Preferably something that will work for os 9. I have an old imac g3 I would like to make programs for. If cpp didn't exist for it, what should I use to program for it? 

For bonus points if you can find a java development kit for power-pc too that would be awesome!

Thank you all in advance:D

Comment: I'd first figure out it's processor type.  Aren't those ARM?

Comment: @annoying_squid Nope, they're PowerPC.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin  Oh yeah.  Got confused as they are both RISC.

Comment: Back in the old days we used MPW on those.  Probably tough to find now.

Answer (score 1):

Well, gcc can compile code for ppc.

You need to install the *toolchain* for the architecture you are targeting.
Search for "cctools" / "binutils" / "crosstools" or "ppc cross-compile environment".

You can also take a look at:

- [Building and Testing gcc/glibc cross toolchains](http://www.kegel.com/crosstool/) (This will probably work)
- [Host/Target specific installation notes for GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/specific.html#powerpc-x-x) (search powerpc in the page)

Unfortunately, I don't have a good java development kit for power-pc to recommend you.

Answer (score 1):

Look for [LLVM](http://llvm.org), they make the official C and related compilers for MacOS. A C compiler should be enough to build it. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) would be my second bet, it certainly handled PowerPC (Linus Torvalds had a G3 Mac as his primary development machine at some point, IIRC). Perhaps a search for unofficial software repositories leads to a working package, or perhaps looking for fan groups of PPC Macs helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official JDK for power-pc anymore.  However, there are ports around if you are prepared to put in some effort yourself.  For example:

- http://javaevangelist.blogspot.com.au/2012/02/openjdk-7-on-apple-g5-powerpc-on-mac-os.html
- [Java 6 on Mac PowerPC with Mac OS X 10.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613175/java-6-on-mac-powerpc-with-mac-os-x-10-4)
- http://openjdk.java.net/projects/bsd-port/

Also, bear in mind that the G3 is [really old](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMac_G3), and the community of people interested in using it and porting stuff to it is likely to be really small.  I'd say that the chances of OS 9 support is pretty minimal.